Multirows in MathJax (or native Stackoverflow tables)?
Yes, I know that tabular is not a math environment and is therefore not part of MathJax.
But ... what about multirows ? Multirows are a perfectly legitimate feature when writing mathematics, and in LaTeX
multirow only works in the tabular environment.
Below is an example I just encountered when answering a question : how do you convert the following LaTeX snippet
to MathJax (or Markdown if it's more suitable) ?
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
Case & Status of $v_3$ & Status of $v_4$  \\
\hline
1 &  \multirow{5}{*}{$v_3 \lt 2v_2-v_1$} & $v_4 \lt v_3-v_2$ \\
\cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
2 &  & $v_4 = v_3-v_2$ \\
\cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
3 &  & $v_3-v_2 \lt v_4 \lt v_2-v_1$ \\
\cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
4 &  & $v_4 = v_2-v_1$ \\
\cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
5 &  & $v_4 \gt v_2-v_1$ \\
\hline
6 & \multirow{3}{*}{$v_3 = 2v_2-v_1$} & $v_4 \lt v_2-v_1$ \\
\cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
7 &  & $v_4 = v_2-v_1$ \\
\cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
8 &  & $v_4 \gt v_2-v_1$ \\
\hline
9 & \multirow{3}{*}{$v_3 \gt 2v_2-v_1$} & $v_4 \lt \frac{v_3-v_1}{2}$ \\
\cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
10 &  & $v_4 = \frac{v_3-v_1}{2}$ \\
\cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
11 &  & $v_4 \gt \frac{v_3-v_1}{2}$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

The LaTeX output :


Tables should probably be formatted with markdown, not MathJax:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support .

@XanderHenderson Thanks for your help. I'm still confused about how I would rewrite my snippet using markdown

I have the impression that MathJax arrays can be nested in both MathJax arrays and Markdown tables.  I'll try to reproduce your figure.

My mistake for not reading the posted question closely enough.  I have edited my answer to use nested arrays to simulate the multirow effect.
Things to note:

Nested arrays are used.  So, if the first item on a row is a nested array, that automatically simulates (in effect) a multirow environment.

I used the ~ command, which (in mathjax) is apparently the same as the \; command, to artificially increase the width of a nested entry. 
This increased the width of the corresponding \hline command.

I could not get (for example) \hrule to work inside the array environment.  So, in the array environment, I am apparently stuck with the \hline command, which takes no parameters.
Note that the horizontal width of the \hline in the nested entries is not perfect.

Note that in the last three nested rows, the vertical placements of the LHS column is slightly misaligned with the vertical placements in the RHS column. 
This is caused by the use of the \frac command in the RHS column.  I briefly experimented with (for example) variations of the \phantom command, inside the array environment : no joy.

I suspect that the {begin array} ... {end array} environment is not the only latex environment supported by mathjax.
I further suspect that other environments (e.g. some form of matrix or align environment) will not only be supported by mathjax, but also permit nested environments. 
As I see it, the two main issues of nested hlines that are not wide enough, plus the vertical misalignment at the bottom of the table may be creatively fixable with other environments.


\begin{array}{| c | c | c |}
  \hline                       
  \text{Case} & \text{Status of} ~v_3 
& \text{Status of} ~v_4  \\
\hline
{\begin {array}{r}
~~~~~1\\ \hline
2 \\ \hline
3 \\ \hline
4 \\ \hline
5 \\ 
\end{array}}
& v_3 > 2v_2 - v_1 
& {\begin {array}{c}
v_4 < v_3 - v_2 \\ \hline
v_4 = v_3 - v_2 \\ \hline
v_3 - v_2 < v_4 < v_2 - v_1 \\
\hline
v_4 = v_2 - v_1 \\ 
\hline
v_4 > v_2 - v_1 \\ 
\end{array}} \\
\hline
{\begin {array}{r}
~~~~~6 \\ \hline
7 \\ \hline
8 \\ 
\end{array}}
& v_3 = 2v_2 - v_1 
& {\begin {array}{c}
~~~~~~~~~~ v_4 < v_2 - v_1 ~~~~~~~~~~ \\
\hline
v_4 = v_2 - v_1 \\ 
\hline
v_4 > v_2 - v_1 \\
\end{array}} \\
\hline
{\begin {array}{r}
9 \\ \hline
~~~~10 \\ \hline
11 \\ 
\end{array}}
& v_3 > 2v_2 - v_1 
& {\begin {array}{c}
~~~~~~~~~~ v_4 < \frac{v_3 - v_2}{2}
~~~~~~~~~~\\ \hline
v_4 = \frac{v_3 - v_2}{2} \\ 
\hline
v_4 > \frac{v_3 - v_2}{2} \\
\end{array}} \\
\hline
\end{array}
\begin{array}{| c | c | c |}
  \hline                       
  \text{Case} & \text{Status of} ~v_3 
& \text{Status of} ~v_4  \\
\hline
{\begin {array}{r}
~~~~~1\\ \hline
2 \\ \hline
3 \\ \hline
4 \\ \hline
5 \\ 
\end{array}}
& v_3 > 2v_2 - v_1 
& {\begin {array}{c}
v_4 < v_3 - v_2 \\ \hline
v_4 = v_3 - v_2 \\ \hline
v_3 - v_2 < v_4 < v_2 - v_1 \\
\hline
v_4 = v_2 - v_1 \\ 
\hline
v_4 > v_2 - v_1 \\ 
\end{array}} \\
\hline
{\begin {array}{r}
~~~~~6 \\ \hline
7 \\ \hline
8 \\ 
\end{array}}
& v_3 = 2v_2 - v_1 
& {\begin {array}{c}
~~~~~~~~~~ v_4 < v_2 - v_1 ~~~~~~~~~~ \\
\hline
v_4 = v_2 - v_1 \\ 
\hline
v_4 > v_2 - v_1 \\
\end{array}} \\
\hline
{\begin {array}{r}
9 \\ \hline
~~~~10 \\ \hline
11 \\ 
\end{array}}
& v_3 > 2v_2 - v_1 
& {\begin {array}{c}
~~~~~~~~~~ v_4 < \frac{v_3 - v_2}{2}
~~~~~~~~~~\\ \hline
v_4 = \frac{v_3 - v_2}{2} \\ 
\hline
v_4 > \frac{v_3 - v_2}{2} \\
\end{array}} \\
\hline
\end{array}

